# Jquery vertical centering..What is the error?

Tags: jquery, css, vertical-alignment, flexslider

Could anyone tell me why this is doesn't work? The problem is when I open the page that at the beginning the `.flex-viewport` is not in the right place as when I resize or I reload the page.

You can see the problem here: http://www2.adcd.ch/?projects=fatti-e-cifre. If you check with smartphone or tablet, you can see what a mean: the image slider at the beginning is not at the vertical middle as you can instead see when reload the page. There are no console error. I premise that I'm not good with jquery and I'm trying to learn! thx in advance.

```js
var halfWindowHeight = jQuery( window ).height()/2;
var halfViewportHeight = jQuery('#content .flexslider .slides li').height()/2;

function putOnTheMiddle(){
    var halfWindowHeight = jQuery( window ).height()/2;
    var halfViewportHeight = jQuery('#content .flexslider .slides li').height()/2;
    var result = parseFloat(halfWindowHeight) - parseFloat(halfViewportHeight);
    var viewportNavHeight =  jQuery('.flex-control-nav li').height();
    var paddingViewNav = jQuery('.flex-control-nav').css('padding-top');
    var totViewNav = parseFloat(viewportNavHeight) + parseFloat(paddingViewNav);

    jQuery('.flex-viewport').css("margin-top", result - parseFloat(totViewNav) + "px");
}


jQuery( window ).load(function(halfViewportHeight){
    putOnTheMiddle()
});

jQuery( window ).resize(function(halfViewportHeight){
    putOnTheMiddle()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually an error.
At the start of page load your div has `margin-top` value of 0, or smth else, but then, when script runs, it applies new margin, though, it moves to it with transition you have given to it.
The cause of this happens is that you are loading your scripts at the bottom of the page, so browser gets them after all DOM is loaded an built.
For all of that you can use some css like

```
#yourdiv{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -half-of-element-heigh;
    margin-left: -half-of-element-width;
}
```

For dynamical height element, you can use `flexbox`:

```
#yourParentdiv{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovmL0tyf/)

Comment: the problem is that i can't know the half of the element on smartphone because the size is different on every type of mobile.. That is why I use jQuery.. I've already tried to load the scripts at the top of the page but nothing change!

Comment: @Michela Updated my answer. Try flexbox:)

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work.. You think there could be another way?

Comment: @Michela didn't work in which way? It didn't center the div or? There is one move way - you can play with `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` on parent div. But I think you've just didn;t specify the height of a parent or didn't remove the margin from the child div, when trying flexbox method.

Comment: something works but the result is not right.. Of sure is my error but I can't understand what I'm wrong!

Comment: @Michela could you please provide some screenshot of what you've get, or some working demo?

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged your code and found that the **paddingViewNav** is coming out to be 15px which is causing the slider to move up more....ideally it should be less for mobile as compared to desktop.